# What do I do with trout slime?

Tags: fish

The trout is covered with slime. I am going to bake it. Should I remove the slime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's fresh Trout with the skin on then yes, rinse the slime off. If it was frozen then you might have another problem...